# Search in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-search

I think the question says it all: What is the best and easiest way to search in a GridView? I want that the user can type a String in the searchbox of the actionbar and than display or hide some items (based on the search string) in the GridView. What is the correctly way for this?

Answer (score 1):

For the GridView you must have a **list of items** and **an adapter**. As you have mentioned, you sort the list on the basis of your input string then call `gridview.notifyDataSetChanged()` method. It will refresh the grid based on your sorted list items. Good luck.